# create HTTP Get request, Open a web page and parse response URL after successful sing-in using c# or javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

How to make an HTTP get request and parse the response?

I'm integrating Outlook calendar with a custom calendar in order to get shared calendar events and display all on a single page without the presence of a user.

I have done that but in a hacky way and I'm now trying to make it cleaner, however, I have hit a roadblock with making the Get request and parsing the response parameters.

What I want to do is to make a sign-up experience for a tenant Admin in Azure ADD:

1. navigate to Microsoft login page
2. grant permissions
3. parse the response and save the tenant ID into local variable.

**I solved the problem! turns out I don't need to parse the response body, instead use the accesstoken to retrive the tenantID after having created the sign-up Experience!**

Comment: is this even possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

alternative way of doing this is found [here](http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/11/18/from-domain-to-tenantid/)